# Python group by columns and make sure values in group doesn't skip values in order of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have 2 dataframes with the following structures:

```
df1
Group1 Group2 Label
G1     A1    AA
G1     A1    BB
G1     A1    CC
G1     A2    AA
G1     A2    CC
G2     A1    BB
G2     A1    DD
G2     A2    AA
G2     A2    CC
G2     A2    DD
G2     A2    BB

df2
ID  Label_ref
1     AA
2     BB
4     CC
5     DD
7     EE
```

I want to group the `df1` based on the `Group1` and `Group2` columns and check if the 'Label' column contains values from `df2` `Label_ref` in order of `ID`.

`Label` on `df1` doesn't need to have all values from `Label_ref` on `df2`, but the values `Label` on `df1` can't skip any `Label_ref` values in the order of `ID`

Expected output:

The group `Group1=G1`, `Group2=A1` doesn't skip any values from `AA` - `CC`. Therefore the rows corresponding to the group are flagged.

The group `Group1=G1`, `Group2=A2` skips values from `BB` but has the value `CC`. Therefore the rows corresponding to the group are not flagged.

The group `Group1=G2`, `Group2=A2` doesn't skip any values from `AA` - `DD` although they are not in order. Therefore the rows corresponding to the group are flagged.

```
Group1 Group2 Label  Flag
G1     A1    AA     1
G1     A1    BB     1
G1     A1    CC     1
G1     A2    AA     0
G1     A2    CC     0
G2     A1    BB     0
G2     A1    DD     0
G2     A2    AA     1
G2     A2    CC     1
G2     A2    DD     1
G2     A2    BB     1
```

I haven't been able to make much progress:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                'Group1': [ 'G1','G1', 'G1','G1','G1',
                            'G2','G2', 'G2','G2','G2','G2'],
                'Group2': ['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2',
                            'A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2'],
                'Label': ['AA','BB','CC','AA','CC','BB',
                            'DD','AA','CC','DD','BB']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                'ID': [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 7],
                'Label_ref': ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE']})
```

A link to a solution or a function/method I can use to achieve this is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapping series:

```
# Create mapping series
smap = pd.Series(*pd.factorize(df2.sort_values('ID')['Label_ref']))
df1['Flag'] = df1['Label'].map(smap)

# Check if flags are consecutive for each group
is_consecutive = lambda x: (~x.diff().gt(1).any()).astype(int)
df1['Flag'] = df1.sort_values('Flag').groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'])['Flag'].transform(is_consecutive)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   Group1 Group2 Label  Flag
0      G1     A1    AA     1
1      G1     A1    BB     1
2      G1     A1    CC     1
3      G1     A2    AA     0
4      G1     A2    CC     0
5      G2     A1    BB     0
6      G2     A1    DD     0
7      G2     A2    AA     1
8      G2     A2    CC     1
9      G2     A2    DD     1
10     G2     A2    BB     1
```